# Trying to build safari extension. Not working -.-

Tags: javascript, safari

So I'm making a Safari extension for my own personal use, and it's not working at all.
I'm trying to skip adf.ly and go directly to the website. But it's not doing anything at all.
I've tried alerting the current URL and the supposed new URL, and they aren't even displaying either.

Global.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script type='application/javascript'>
// Skip Adf.ly 
// Made by Austen Patterson
// For Safari
//(C) Copyright 2013 Austen Patterson.

safari.application.addEventListener("start", performCommand, true);  
safari.application.addEventListener("validate", validateCommand, true);


// Function to perform when event is received  
function performCommand(event) {  
    // Make sure event comes from the button  
    if (event.command == "skip") {  
    var url = this.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.url;
    var newurl = url.replace(/http:\/\/adf\.ly\/(\d+)\//, '');
    location.href(newurl);
    window.open(newurl,"_self");
    return;

    }  
}  

</script>
```

and here is my extension builder settings. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `alert` from the global page. You can use console.debug, though, so that should help.

The bigger issue though is that you're treating the global page as though it has access to the page you're trying to modify via the `window` object. It doesn't work that way. `location.href` doesn't point to anything and `window.open` will probably not work from the global scope. (These are both leaky globals, which is something you want to avoid.) I haven't tested it, but something like this should work:

```
safari.application.addEventListener("beforeNavigate", function adflyChecker(event) {
    var url = event.url.replace(/http:\/\/adf\.ly\/(\d+)\//, '');
    safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.url = url;
}, true);
```

This has the advantage of working on navigate and not requiring you to manually click the button. If you configure your extension to only apply to `adf.ly` URLs, then you can be sure that your code only fires when it's appropriate.

More information about the architecture of Safari extensions is available [in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/ExtensionsOverview/ExtensionsOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH15-SW4).